# get rows from database where user is member

Tags: mysql

I have this table in my MySQL database:

[image]

I need a query, but I have a logical problem to "create" them.

I am User with userID "3".

I would like to get all userIDs, which have the same chatToken like me, but without me in the result.

The result should be: userID "1" and "2".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your sample data, `userID` 3 appears twice and has two different `chatToken`s. So you want any user that has any one of your `chatToken`s but is not you (i.e. whose `userID` is **not** 3)

```sql
select userID
  from table
 where chatToken in (select chatToken
                       from table
                      where userID = 3)
   and userId != 3
```